# Different pdf when compiling on different computers: prevent empty new line break before equation

Tags: equations, line-numbering

I have two different computers (without the same pdflatex versions/packages but both are recents).

However, when compiling the same document I do not get the same pdf outputs.
I noticed than for one of them if a line is "too long" before an equation then in the pdf it result in an empty line being added before that equation.
I put below 2 screen shots of the same document compiled on the two computers.
As you can see the line `632` is only present on one of them.

I would like to prevent such empty line from being added before an equation because the latex text is the following:

```latex
The Brout-Englert-Higgs (BEH) mechanism introduces a scalar Higgs term to the SM Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{Higgs}} = (D^{\mu} \phi)^{\dag}(D_{\mu} \phi) - V(\phi),
  \label{eq:Theory_HiggsLagrangian}
\end{equation}
```

[image]
[image]

NB: if the text would be shorter (i.e. I remove few words) then that empty line disappears.
Would anyone have an idea of what is going on here?
Many thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: if you get different output you have different package version somewhere. Please provide an example that shows the problem. Presumably, although you do not mention it, you are asking about the `lineno` package?

Comment: add `\listfiles` to your preamble  and then show the list at the end of the log on the two machines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks indeed I found a solution (see post below) 
The `lineno` and `hyperref` packages are somehow interfering

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix it,
I put a reproducible example and the solution in case it can be useful to someone else.
The issue can be fixed by including `lineno` after `hyperref`.
Somehow the two packages are interfering and `lineno` was causing the addition of one line.
If one inverts the order of the two packages in the example below one gets either the left or the right output (I increased voluntarily the space taken by a line so that it is pretty visible)

[image]

Example were an extra line is wrongly added (right of the image):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{ 
  amsmath   ,
  lineno    ,
  hyperref  
}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers%
\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{12pt}{60pt}\selectfont% 
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}%

The Brout-Englert-Higgs (BEH) mechanism introduces a scalar Higgs term to the SM Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{Higgs}} = (D^{\mu} \phi)^{\dag}(D_{\mu} \phi) - V(\phi),
  \label{eq:Theory_HiggsLagrangian}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The fix (left of the image) is to use instead:

```latex
\usepackage{ 
  amsmath   ,
  hyperref  ,
  lineno
}
```

Comment: well yes, hyperref should almost always be loaded last. next time please put the examples in the question not the answer, otherwise basically no one but you has the information to make an answer.

Comment: but this does not answer the question as asked which states you get different output from the  _same_ doument, so the answer should involve updating one of the systems, not editing the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes sorry but I asked the question without the example first because the issue I was facing is coming from my thesis which has a lot of packages included. Providing a simple example took me some time like I was removing all the unnecessary packages and while doing that I found the problem

Comment: That's what always happens, which is why we always say to make an example.

Comment: Yes sure I will provide an example next time

Comment: A possibility: Even with the same packages and TeX year, are the fonts on the two systems exactly the same? That is, does one system read some fonts from a system font directory, while the other reads them fromn a user or TeX font directory? In rare cases, a font designer will tweak something (bearings, kerning) that can cause different line breaks. Understand that this is probably not the explanation for the specific question, but an "in general" thing.